# How to refetch data for server component while navigating in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a protected server component that display's user data:

```
import styles from "@/styles/app/Account.module.scss";
import { getUserId } from "@/utils/auth";
import { getAccountAge } from "@/utils/helpers";
import { getAccessTokenServerSide } from "@/utils/serverSide";

interface AccountDetails {
  email: string;
  account_type: "regular" | "google" | "facebook";
  created_at: string;
  account_age?: string;
}

const getAccountDetails = async () => {
  const accessToken = await getAccessTokenServerSide();
  const userId = getUserId(accessToken);
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/user/${userId}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      cache: "no-store",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "x-access-token": `${accessToken}`,
      },
    }
  );
  const data = (await response.json()) as AccountDetails;
  const account_age = getAccountAge(data.created_at);
  data.account_age = account_age;
  return data;
};

const UserProfile = ({
  accountDetails,
}: {
  accountDetails: AccountDetails;
}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.userProfile}>
      <div className={styles.userInfo}>
        <p>Email: email@email.com</p>
        <p>Account Type: {accountDetails.account_type}</p>
        <p>Account Age: {accountDetails.account_age} days</p>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.actions}>
        <button>Change Email</button>
        <button>Change Password</button>
        <button>Delete Account</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Account = async () => {
  const accountDetails = await getAccountDetails();
  return (
    <main className={styles.Account}>
      <h1>Account Management</h1>
      <UserProfile accountDetails={accountDetails} />
    </main>
  );
};

export default Account;
```

The problem that I have is that the data obtained via getAccountDetails function is not refetched during later requests, i.e. the data is fetched on the initial request, but if I then navigate to homepage and back again to the Account page, the data is not refetched.

This leads to two issues:

1. The Account page is protected, so if the getAccessTokenServerSide function call fails because the user is not authenticated, it redirects them to the login page. Due to data not being refetched, this protection mechanism does not work.
2. When user changes their account data, it is not being reflected on their Account page

One hacky way to solve it was to nest the UserProfile component within the Account component, and call a router.refresh() in a useEffect, but this seems wrong, because it leads to the page rendering two times, even on the initial render, which always fetches correct data.

Is there a way to always refetch new data while navigating back to a previously rendered server component?